# Error on compilation for WiaDevMgr instance creation

Tags: c++

I followed all the steps from wia tutorial when I declared and created an instance for WiaDevMgr2, but the linker gave me the following error messages:

```
"error LNK2020: unresolved token(0A000014) CLSID_WiaDevMgr";
and
"error LNK2020: unresolved token(0A000015) IID_IWiaDevMgr";
```

There is something I should add, but I don't know what and where in my code. The code lines for WiaDevMgr instance creation are as below:

```
    IWiaDevMgr2 **ppWiaDevMgr;
    *ppWiaDevMgr = NULL;

    //
    // Create an instance of the device manager
    //


    //I am in the situation for Vista OS or later:
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance( CLSID_WiaDevMgr2, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IWiaDevMgr2, (void**)ppWiaDevMgr );
```

Comment: You could at least link this tutorial, if you're not going to quote the build/linking commands used. There's probably not enough here to draw any useful conclusion.

Comment: Project > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies, add WiaGuid.lib.  Or do it in source code with `#pragma comment(lib, "WiaGuid.lib")`.

Comment: Sorry, the link is:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms629848(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I added WiaGuid.lib in my project dependencies and another linker error arose: 
Form1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "long __stdcall CoCreateInstance(struct test_wia::_GUID const &,struct test_wia::IUnknown *,unsigned long,struct test_wia::_GUID const &,void * *)" (?CoCreateInstance@@$$J220YGJABU_GUID@test_wia@@PAUIUnknown@2@K0PAPAX@Z)
C:\Users\Mihai\Documents\Visual Studio Projects\test_wia\Debug\test_wia.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
I included the CoCreateInstance header declaration: